# How to drive 180v DC motor connected to mains?

Tags: transistors, dc-motor, mains, igbt

I have a brushed dc treadmill motor, and I'm trying to understand the motor controller board circuit. The board is converting 220v ac signal with just a bridge rectifier and driving the motor with an IGBT. The IGBT is a 20N60 and is switching the positive voltage. I'm trying to put together the similar circuit for using this motor, and is there any reason to use an IGBT for high side switching? Is there a safe alternative to power a 180v motor?

Comment: Bring more details. Type of motor, why you need controller, etc.

Comment: @user263983 It's a similar motor like this [link](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/RUoAAOSwA4dWNQIZ/s-l300.jpg)
180v  4 amps max, Im trying to a similar controller for running the motor as a treadmill itself. 
I have found the exact same controller [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maw1yFxSSjA)

Comment: Engineers are not getting their information from youtube clips and photos of device. Specifications and schematics needed. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: THere are numerous treadmill controller circuits on web. An IGBT is probably used duie to switching speed, and voltage considerations.  You can switch high or low, MOSFET, IGBT, Bipolar if you have an appropriate design.

Answer (score 1):

High side switching is generally safer. Also some IGBT circuitry only support high side switching.

Just buy a motor controller, they are not expensive.